# Creating a dictionary interface and applying methods to it

Tags: java, generics, dictionary, interface, abstract-class

I  have some doubts about creating a custom dictionary in java and applying methods to it.

This is my code:

```
public interface Dictionary<K, V> {
  V find(K key);
  void add(K key, V value);
  void remove(K key);
}
```

and

```
public class redblack implements Dictionary{ 

    @Override
    public Object find(Object key) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void add(Object key, Object value) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void remove(Object key) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

But the "Dictionary" is underlined in yellow saying `( References to generic type dictionary<K,V> should be parameterized.`

Now I'm actually confused; why did I get generated methods with "Object" parameters when they should be generic types like `<T>`?

If I want to implement a generic abstract type, what should I do?

Comment: "Now I'm actually confused, why i got generated methods with " Object" parameters when they should be generic types like ?" - well we can't tell that without knowing how you generated them. But it sounds like you should have `public class RedBlack<K, V> implements Dictionary<K, V>`.

Comment: Don't use [**raw types**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/rawTypes.html).

Comment: What should I use then?

Comment: You need to realise the types in some way. Either parameterise the extended type, and pass the parameters up through the 'implements...' clause, or use concrete types for the type parameters. It depends on whether redblack class is supposed to be generic or not.

Comment: It's supposed to be generic!

Comment: So , it's ok i guess now . I have no errors with your suggestions. It just make a huge confusion to me all those things, since on the web there are so many answer but not clear at all.

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this:

```
public class RedBlack<K, V> implements Dictionary<K, V> {
....
}
```

and also make it `abstract` if you don't want to implement these Methods in this class.